# Show in Dock if application is open in current Mission Control space

Tags: dock, spaces, mission-control

When I run an application, it shows a little dot next to the application icon in Dock, signifying that the application is running:

[image: Terminal.app with dot next to it, signifying the application is running]

The problem is that I have no way of knowing whether the app is running on the current space. What I want to do is "show Terminal if it's already running on the current space". Otherwise I would open a new Terminal instance! Currently I have no way of knowing if it's open on the current space, which is very annoying.

Is there an idiomatic way in macOS for accomplishing what I'm trying to do? I.e., a fast way for showing Terminal on the current space. Command+Tab has the same behaviour.

I'm thinking about whether it's possible to patch Dock.app.. am I doing something wrong? ;)